# Passing variable from Javascript to Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

In rails you can do this:

```
<% name = @user.name %>
<script>
    var name = <%= name%>;
    alert(name);
    //prints the name of the user
</script>
```

You can do this in reverse, like this

```
<% name = @user.name %>
<script>
    var name = "John";
    <% name %> = name;
</script>

<% @user.name = name %>

<%= name %>
<!-- prints the name of the user, in this case "John" -->
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but for the purpose of an example

The point is, can you pass the value of a javascript variable to a ruby variable in rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't pass a variable directly from javascript to rails:

- **Ruby on Rails**' code is executed on the **server-side**, to generate the page (with HTML, CSS, and Javascript).
- **Javascript**'s code is executed on the **client-side**, by the browser.

**The only way** to communicate client -> server is to use a request. You can **use AJAX** (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) to send a request from the client to the server without reloading the page.

---

You have to understand some concepts about code on the server vs client side. The process of "displaying a page from a website":

- (**Client**-side) The user sends an HTTP request to the server for a page, sending the location of the page, example: `http://myapp.com/users`
- (**Server**-side) The server gets the request, find the proper controller/action following the defined routes
- (**Server**-side) The server generates the page in HTML/CSS/Javascript to send back to the user. It generates the HTML via the views & partials, executes the ruby code of these pages.
- (**Server**-side) Once the page is rendered, the server sends the HTTP response with the HTML/CSS/Javascript in the body.
- (**Client**-side) The client's browser receives the response of the server and reads the body composed of HTML/CSS/Javascript (mostly). The browser parses and renders the HTML/CSS, and execute the javascript.