# Javascript variable inside Erb Tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to access a javascript variable in js.erb file inside erb tag. for example

my_variable = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];

@project = Project.find(my_variable)

So is there a way to pass 'my_variable' in the 'find' helper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable from Javascript to Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057067/passing-variable-from-javascript-to-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422497/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-ruby or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959770/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-into-a-erb-code-in-a-js-view or...

Comment: You need to keep in mind that your erb code (the ruby code) is evaluated **on the server** where there is no window etc, and no client at all: the client stuff (ie your js.erb code) happens LATER.  So this is like trying to reach into the future to read a variable.  If you want the client to pass information to the server then it needs to be part of a request back to the server - in a cookie or in params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do with https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs , as you can see

```
require "execjs"
ExecJS.eval "'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"
```

You can get the returning value easily.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to get the URI on the rails side, fetch the project(s) and parse them to JSON - reparse them in js.erb and send the contents of the file to the client.

This way you do not have to execute JS on your server and you'll still have the project within the JS file you need.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails) explains how to get the request URI for different rails versions.

> ### For Rails 3.2 or Rails 4+
>
> You should use `request.original_url` to get the current URL.
>
> This method is documented at
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url,
>   but if you're curious, the implementation is:
>
> ```
> def original_url
>     base_url + original_fullpath
> end
> ```
>
> ### For Rails 3:
>
> You can write
>   `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"`,
>   since `request.url` is now deprecated.

### EDIT (20-11-2015)

Since you seem to be requiring a specific segment of the url, you could mimic the JS implementation with ruby easily by simply calling `original_url.split('/')[2]`